# WebSphere 8 persistence.xml syntax error (expected root element)

Tags: java, xml, jpa, persistence, websphere-8

Installing my web application to WebSphere Application Server 8 fails due to a syntax error in my persistence.xml. According to my IDE, there is no error. What is the actual problem?

persistence.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
  >
      <persistence-unit name="myapp">
          <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
      </persistence-unit>
  </persistence>
```

Excerpts from stack trace (SystemOut.log):

1:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.metadata.MetaDataException: CWWJP0040E: The persistence.xml in application PA_Appl, module Appl-0.1.war, has a syntax error at line number: 6, column number: 2.
```

2:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: expected root element {http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence}persistence
```

Please comment, if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="myapp">
          <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
      </persistence-unit>
  </persistence>
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't change xmlns value. Now it works. But I don't understand, why 2.0 - I'm using Hibernate 4.3 which implements JPA 2.1

Comment: I think the problem was due to the xmlns only, otherwise you could try again to change the version to 2.1.

Comment: Your JPA provider might support JPA 2.1, but the JPA container included in WebSphere Application Server does not. The JPA container locates and processes persistence.xml at application start, and then passes the information to the JPA provider.